# How to Use xmltask.jar inside build.xml placed inside any_path/ant/lib folder inspite of having pre-installed ant in the enviromnent

Tags: ant, redhat

I have ant installed in my RedHat 7 machine. I have a project which has ant libraries inside  lib folder. That lib folder is  present  inside installer. There  is a jar file known as xmltask.jar inside lib folder.  I had defined

```
<property name="dependencyfinder.home" value="."/>
<taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask">        
    <classpath location="${dependencyfinder.home}/lib/xmltask.jar"/>
</taskdef>
```

In that line i am getting

BUILD FAILED
installer\build.xml:37: taskdef class com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Total time: 296 milliseconds

I am using an install script for executing build.xml which is responsible to set the class path.
The code for the  script is as  follows:

```
OLD_DIR=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}

ANT_HOME=$SCRIPT_DIR/ant
ANT_LIB=${ANT_HOME}/lib

${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -q -e

cd ${OLD_DIR}
exit 0
```

Comment: There's most likely something wrong with that classpath location. Try adding an `<echo>` line that prints out `${dependencyfinder.home}` to make sure this property is being properly set (you'll probably have to temporarily comment out your taskdef so your script doesn't immediately fail).

Comment: thanks @CAustin
 i had  mentioned  about the  classpath and i dependencyfinder.home was returning . which was  assigned to. The folder does not  contain lib but it has  ant/lib